# Trying to get maven antrun plugin to work

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

Trying to get antrun plugin to work:

To get this to work I have assumed I need to included two entries in pom.xml:

the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target name="usage">
                        <echo message="This is how this target is used!"/>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I don't know what phase to specify (I only want a standalone process to push my artifact to a remote server - that is the purpose of the antrun plugin, AFAIK, anyway. My intention is to use these ant targets as a way to ease in to migrating my entire build from Ant to Maven). Does my antrun target/s have to be run as part of a phase?

When I try to run this('org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:antrun:1.7:package') from STS(debug on), I get the following output:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: /home/juser/dev/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/sagerbe-maven-trial-4/EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-45-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/juser/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/juser/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/juser/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.sagerbe:web:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:antrun is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.144s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 20 10:14:39 SAST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:antrun or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:antrun: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:pom:antrun in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:antrun or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:antrun
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:antrun
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:pom:antrun in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:pom:antrun in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:230)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:204)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:427)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

The above-mentioned 'PluginResolutionException' wiki page gives some advice but I'm none the wiser. (I can see the plugin directory and files in my local m2 repository, so if it can't download it from the central maven repository, why is it not looking in my local repo?)

When I look in '~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.7', I see these files:

- m2e-lastUpdated.properties
- maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.jar.sha1
- maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.pom.sha1
- maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.jar
- maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.pom
- _maven.repositories

... so surely this means I have the jar dependency and pom file requirement satisfied.

Should I be configuring a proxy? If so, why? What is the purpose of proxy configuration?

Comment: Ah. I got it to work.

The following dependencies I had declared in pom.xml but outside of the plugin:

  <dependency>
   <groupId>ant</groupId>
   <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.3-1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.tools.ant</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.50</version>
  </dependency>

I moved these into the scope of the antrun plugin element. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked adding the antrun maven dependencies like this:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>ant</groupId> 
<artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId> 
<version>1.5.3-1</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId> 
 <artifactId>jsch</artifactId> 
 <version>0.1.50</version> 
 </dependency>
```

Thanks for posting your fix Jim!!!